# My MacBook Pro mid-2010 won't recognize new hard drive

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I was forced to change my HD since the old one gives me I/O error on boot.

I bought a Western Digital Blue WD5000LPVX, connected by USB to another Mac and format it using Mac OS Extended (Journaled) file system.

When I change the new hard drive and boot OS X Mavericks from USB drive, going to Disk Utility the new HD isn't recognized.

Is it a wrong HD for my Mac? Why isn't it shown in Disk Utility?

<sup>Using a MacBook Pro mid-2010</sup>

Comment: How precisely is the hard drive connected to the Mac? When you open System Information (or system profiler on older OS - you don't mention what OS you are running) is that hardware listed under the appropriate bus? I check there and if it's not even on the bus, it's a failure of the cable or the device in most cases.'

Comment: What *exactly* does "I/O Error on Boot" mean? Also can you share a picture of.... DAMNIT @Community strikes again, this is a 4 year old post.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for you since you've got an error on boot, but if your OLD drive can get into recovery mode, I did a pretty extensive write up on swapping hard drives here: [How do i install OS X on new hard drive? I have macbook pro mid 2010.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/190697/how-do-i-install-os-x-on-new-hard-drive-i-have-macbook-pro-mid-2010/205063#205063)

If it doesn't, based on my research, you'll need another Mac to create a bootable install from a USB device of at least 8 GB.

This question is really old, but just in case someone runs across it, I figured I'd put in my $.02. In addition sometimes this problem may occur due to the HDD cable itself failing a Apple known problem with this model. In which case a new cable usually allows communication with the HDD to work internally as it should. While many Hdd refused to work internally they booted externally just fine.  These cables run $30 to $60 depending on where you buy.