# How do i install OS X on new hard drive? I have macbook pro mid 2010.

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I have 13 inch mid 2010 macbook pro. Just installed new 1T hard drive but now am hesitating on what to do next. I have my old hard drive converted to external drive and a back up drive as well.